# How to format code containing random numbers into a service and support methods?

Tags: java, random, service, java.util.scanner

I'm just having trouble with a specific question. My task is to write a program (Rearrange this code) which displays a random integer within a specific range. The app class should read the high and low integer values required from the user. create an instance of the support class, and display the result of a call to the random range method. The support class should contain no date fields and just one method. I'm a real newbie and when I arrange it keep getting errors to do with the the randomRange not being resolved to a type. If anyone could rearrange this in a way that works and tell me what you did along the way, it'd be great. Thanks :)

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomApp{

  public static void main(String[]args){ 
    int lo = readInt("Enter lowest value");
    int hi = readInt("Enter highest value");
    RandomRange r = new RandomRange();
    System.out.println("Random integer between " + lo + " and " + hi + " : " + r.randomRange(lo, hi)); 
  }

  public static int readInt(String message){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(message);
    return sc.nextInt();
  } 
  /** Returns an integer entered by the user*/

}
```

Another class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


public class RandomRange{

/** Returns random integer between high and low parameters.*/
public int randomRange(int low, int high){
  Random generator = new Random();
  return generator.nextInt(high-low+1) + low;
}
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: So far, I've got the above haha (See edit)

Comment: Means, have you got some output?

Comment: When I compile I keep getting RandomRange cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: And are all your class in same file? or different file?

Comment: Different files
File: C:\Users\ella\Documents\RandomApp.java  [line: 9]
Error: RandomRange cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Did you follow my answer?

Comment: and what is on line 9

Comment: tick mark my answer then :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't imported the class

Do the following after importing Scanner:

```
**import your.package.RandomRange;**
```

If you are using **Eclipse** then you can simply press **ctrl+shift+o**

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for me.(I did not check the logical part)

I have added few line to test it :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomApp{

  public static void main(String[]args){ 
    int lo = readInt("Enter lowest value");
    int hi = readInt("Enter highest value");
    RandomRange r = new RandomRange();
    System.out.println("Random integer between " + lo + " and " + hi + " : " + r.randomRange(lo, hi)); 
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
      System.out.println(r.randomRange(lo, hi));

  }

  public static int readInt(String message){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(message);
    return sc.nextInt();
  } 
  /** Returns an integer entered by the user*/

}

//import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.Random;
 class RandomRange{

/** Returns random integer between high and low parameters.*/
   public int randomRange(int low, int high){
  Random generator = new Random();
  return generator.nextInt(high-low+1) + low;
 }
}
```

Compile : `javac RandomApp.java`

Run : `java RandomApp`